# Dynamic programming table for finding similar substrings is too large

Tags: strings, dynamic-programming, substrings

> **Substring Diff**
>   Given two strings of length $n$, $P = p_1\dots p_n$ and $Q = q_1 \dots q_n$, we define $M(i, j, L)$ as the number of
>   mismatches between $p_i \dots p_{i+L-1}$ and $q_j \dots q_{j+L-1}$. In set
>   notation, $M(i, j, L)$ refers to the size of the set $\{0 \leq x < L \mid p_{i + x} \neq q_{j + x}\}$.
>
> Given an integer $K$, your task is to find the maximum length $L$ such
>   that there exists pair of indices $(i,j)$ for which we have $M(i, j, L) \leq K$. Of course, we should also have $i + L - 1 \leq n$ and $j + L - 1 \leq n$.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - $0 \leq K \leq |P|$
> - Both $P$ & $Q$ would have the same length
> - The size of each of the string would be at the max **1500**
> - All characters in $P$ and $Q$ are lower-case English letters.

The recursive function will have the form:

```
longest(string1, string2, allowed_mismatches) = 
    {
        ... (something :P )
    }
```

The state space then has size $K^3$. With an upper bound on $K$ of 1500, the running time and space usage will be terrible... So direct dynamic programming will not work without some additional property to reduce the state space.

Ideas?

**UPDATE**

Using the ideas suggested by both Yuval and Vor, I came up with the following solution that works like a charm, running in $O(K^2)$ time and using $K$ space.

```
def longest_range_min_sum(str1, str2, start1, start2, slice_size, max_sum):
    longest = 0
    i = 0
    running_sum = 0
    while i + longest < slice_size:
        if str1[start1 + i + longest] != str2[start2 + i + longest]:
            running_sum += 1
        if running_sum > max_sum:
            if str1[start1 + i] != str2[start2 + i]:
                running_sum -= 1
            i += 1
        else:
            longest += 1
    return longest

import sys

data = sys.stdin.readlines()
num_cases = int(data.pop(0))
for ignore in xrange(num_cases):
    max_mismatches, str1, str2 = data.pop(0).split()
    max_mismatches = int(max_mismatches)
    m = n = len(str1)
    longest = 0
    for i in xrange(m + n + 1):
        if i > n:
            slice_size = m - (i - n)
        else:
            slice_size = min(i, m)
        if slice_size == 0:
            continue
        end1 = max(m, m - i)
        if i > n:
            end1 = m - (i - n)
        start1 = end1 - slice_size
        end2 = min(i, n)
        start2 = end2 - slice_size
        #print zeros_and_ones 
        #print str1[start1:end1], ' - ', str2[start2:end2]
        longest_in_sub = longest_range_min_sum(str1, str2, start1, start2, slice_size, max_mismatches)
        #print longest_in_sub
        longest = max(longest, longest_in_sub)
    print longest
```

Comment: If you *have* to copy&paster contest problems here, please restrict yourself to the essentials *and link the source*. "the recursion above will fail" is not a very meaningful statement; I'm sure the solution is well-defined, you just run out of memory (?).

Comment: Yep, run out of memory. Don't have 1500^3 ~ 2^30 bytes of ram free...

Comment: Did you run out of heap or was it a stack overflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can reduce your problem to the following. Given a sequence of $N$ numbers, find a contiguous subsequence of length at most $K+1$ having maximal sum. This problem, in turn, is solvable in time $O(N)$.

What's the connection between your problem and mine? Let the positions of the mistakes be $I_1,\ldots,I_t$, and add $I_0 = 0$, $I_{t+1} = N+1$. The sequence in question is $J_1 = I_1 - I_0,\ldots,J_{t+1}=I_{t+1}-I_t$. Every $K+1$ consecutive numbers $J_a,\ldots,J_{a+K}$ correspond to a maximal solution for your problem of length $J_a + \cdots + J_{a+K} - 1$. The entire algorithm takes linear time.

Edit: This calculates the maximal $L$ such that $M(i,i,L) \leq K$ for some $i$. The actual problem wanted to find the maximal $L$ such that $M(i,j,L) \leq K$ for some $i,j$. By considering all possible shifts, we can solve this in $O(N^2)$ time and $O(K)$ space.

Comment: Hello Yuval. Can you explain how the reduction works?

Comment: The basic idea is that (up to endpoints) the optimal solution is maximal, in the sense that it is bordered by mismatch on both sides. So it is enough to consider stretches starting and ending with a mismatch, and having $K$ mismatches inside. The length of the stretch is related to the distance between each mismatch and the one following it. This is captured by the sequence $J$. Now you form the appropriate optimization problem, and it turns out that it can be solved very efficiently.

Comment: But what is the reduction algorithm? How do I transform strings P and Q into one sequence?

Comment: You calculate the positions of the mismatches $I$, and from them you construct the sequence $J$. If you're careful, you can run the entire algorithm with memory $O(K)$.

Comment: But then don't you have to calculate the position of the mistakes for every combination of P[i:] and Q[j:]? Then for each combination i and j, you'd create the sequence you mentioned. But then running time is O(K^3), too large with a bound of 1500 on K.

Comment: No, I'm afraid you missed the entire point of the algorithm. It works in linear time. It first constructs the sequence $J$, and then runs the linear time algorithm from the first paragraph. If you implement it this way, then it uses space $O(N)$, but looking at the first paragraph algorithm, we see that by generating $J$ "online", the memory reduces to $O(K)$.

Comment: Yuval, I don't understand... Could you clarify by posting in pseudo code the reduction algorithm that accepts two string P and Q and a parameter K (maximum number of mismatches)? And perhaps the algorithm for solving the new problem?

Comment: Yuval, repeating the comment I made to Vor on his solution: "But this assumes that the longest range must start at the same position for both strings P and Q, when in fact if you look at the problema statement, the longest range can be P[i, length], Q[j, length]."

Comment: You're right. That just multiplies the running time by $K$ (check all the shifts). I don't know if you can do it any faster. Still, instead of $O(N^3)$ we brought it down to $O(N^2)$.

Answer (score 5):

Using Yuval's reduction, the problem can be reformulated as "Find the largest range $(i,j)$ in a binary string $S \in \{0,1\}^*$ such that the number of $1$s contained in the range is $\leq K$" (see [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6076/longest-range-with-sum-smaller-than-k)).

The idea is to start with an initial valid range $(0,j)$ of length $maxlen$ and then shift the "window" $(i,i+maxlen)$ to the right, checking at every step if maxlen can be increased.

This is the pseudocode of a possible solution:

```
 INPUT : string P and Q of length n, integer K
         // string indexes are 0 based (P[0] = first char of P)
 maxidx = 0   // position of the largest interval
 maxlen = 0   // length of the largest interval
 i = 0        // current position of the "window" (i,i+maxlen)
 diffsum = 0  // sum of the mismatches in the range (i,i+maxlen)
 while ( i + maxlen < n ) do
   // update the number of mismatches of the window:
   if (P[i + maxlen] != Q[i + maxlen]) then diffsum = diffsum + 1 
   if diffsum <= K
     then begin
       maxlen = maxlen + 1 // expand window
       maxidx = i  // update base pointer
     end
     else begin
       if (P[i] != Q[i]) then diffsum = diffsum - 1 // discard mismatches out of the window
       i = i + 1 // shift window to the right
     end

 OUTPUT : if maxlen > 0 
            then output (maxidx, maxidx + maxlen - 1) // output the largest interval
            else output("no range with # of mismatches <= K")
```

Time complexity: $O(n)$, space $O(1)$.

Comment: But this assumes that the longest range must start at the same position for both strings P and Q, when in fact if you look at the problema statement, the longest range can be P[i, length], Q[j, length].

Comment: @Alexandre: you are right I quickly posted the answer which works well with the other question "Longest range with sum smaller than K", without looking at the details of this one :-( ... I'll try to fix it later (or move this answer to the other question :)

Comment: @Alexandre: you can use iterate an index $j$ in $[0..n-maxlen-1]$ and call the above function (change the two **if**s to: "... P[i + maxlen] != Q[j + maxlen] ..." and "...P[i] != Q[j]..."). The complexity increases to $O(n^2)$. Do you need the details?

Comment: I gave the answer to Yuval because he had the insight that solved the problem, though I think you expressed his ideas in a much more didactic manner. Wish I could award you points as well. I upvoted your answer. Thanks!