# Longest range with sum smaller than K

Tags: subsequences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic programming table for finding similar substrings is too large](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4994/dynamic-programming-table-for-finding-similar-substrings-is-too-large)

Say I have a sequence $S$ of 0s and 1s such as $S = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]$

How would I efficiently find a pair $(i, j)$ such that $j - i$ is maximum and $(\sum_{z=i}^j S_z ) \leq K$

**UPDATE**

The following algorithm solves the above problem in O(n).

```
def longest_range_min_sum(S, K):
    longest = 0
    i = 0
    running_sum = 0
    while i + longest < len(S):
        if S[i + longest] == 1:
            running_sum += 1
        if running_sum > K:
            if S[i] == 1:
                running_sum -= 1
            i += 1
        else:
            longest += 1
    return longest
```

Comment: A hint: start with i=0 and find the max $j$ for which $\sum_{z=0}^j S_z \leq K$, and set $maxlen=j$; then "shift" the interval $[i,i+maxlen]$ to the right ($i=1,2,...$); at each step check if maxlen can be increased ...

Comment: @Vor This is a simpler version of my answer in the linked question. Could you add it there as an alternative answer?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: ok, I added the answer to that question; do you think I should add it here, too?